# Is there a possibility to live in France on long term basis under these conditions?

Tags: visa, working-visas, france, eu, europe

I am a citizen from India and I am living in France since 1 month for my 1 year masters degree. This venture has been possible only because I was given scholarship by the university.

I am from a political/ religious ideology (exact details I don't want to share) which is very much marginalized in my home country. Due to this marginalization, my mental health was also affected and I take pills of anxiety and depression.

Due to this issue, I don't want to return to my home country as I will be very well pushed to brink of suicide in case I want to continue my career path.

To continue my current career path, there is no other option for me except living in Europe.

I don't have any other guidance, so I thought I should ask here as I am in need of guidance.

**I wanted to know how to continue living in France legally on a Visa. (I am taking France as an example only because I am currently living here and knowing it about France will give me at least an estimate about situation in other nations in the region, I might move to any other country in nearby part of Europe)** *I am not interested in knowing about how to get asylum in France or how to get visa by marrying a French Person. I am only interested in visa if I get a job in France. I am also not interested in becoming a French citizen as even getting to live in France legally will be a huge relief for me.*

> Currently, I am on a student visa of 1 year. So, at the end of the year, I will try my best to find a job and I hope I can get in the areas I want to work in. I think the French government also gives a time limit of 1 year where an Indian citizen can live and find a job in France. (Due to pact with Indian Government). So, what happens after I get a job? Will the employer give me a visa so that I can continue to live in France?

Kindly let me know this! (I know that this situation I mentioned might not be told in a legal language/ bureaucratic language but I don't know that language).

Comment: A couple of points raised by the clarifying parts of the question: first, living in France legally for a certain period is anyway a prerequisite to obtaining French nationality, so even if that were your goal you'd need to answer this question first, and second, even if asylum or similar protection is out of scope for this question, you might be well advised to consider whether you can obtain it if your other options do not work.  Protecting people from political and religious persecution is the point of the asylum system after all.

Comment: @phoog All good points, especially given the OP's citizenship but technically, I know at least one scenario where it's possible to become French without ever living in France (by *déclaration* after being married to a French citizen for some time if you are yourself an EU / EEA or Swiss citizen). I actually know a Swiss citizen who became French by marriage with another Swiss citizen who had become French during an earlier marriage…

Comment: @Relaxed thanks for pointing that out.  I'm aware that most countries have some exceptions to the usual routes that require a period of residence, but I was unaware of this one.  Most of the exceptions I _am_ aware of are in the nature of national-interest grants of naturalization by decree or similar (how Máxima of the Netherlands became Dutch, for example, or how Gérard Depardieu acquired Russian citizenship).  I was aware that some other countries permit their citizens' spouses to become citizens without residence, but I didn't know about France.

Answer (score 5):

If you read French, [service-public.fr](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F2229) has a relatively clear (non-bureaucratic) overview of the rules.

This transition is not always *easy* but graduating in France does open a somewhat *easier* path to a work permit (compared to securing a visa from abroad, especially through lower income thresholds to qualify for a given permit). After you find a job, you will need to apply for a residence permit yourself. Your employer cannot give you a visa nor even apply on your behalf but the work contract or offer is one of the documents you will have to submit to get it.

The main requirement is finding a job paying more than about €30k per year. If you find a job paying more than €40k per year, you can even apply for something called a *passeport talent*, which has several advantages for you. Jobs like that do exist in business and engineering but not all fresh graduates earn this much money in their first job out of school.